# How to model a generic type

Tags: oop, software-design, class-diagram, astah

I am using Astah to create class diagrams (for a TypeScript application). I am trying to add a function keys that returns an IterableIterator of type T.

My problem is that every time I hit enter `keys():IterableIterator<T>` is changed to `keys():IterableIterator<T, ?>`. Am I trying to add it incorrectly (first time modelling generics or is this a problem/setting in Astah (the design tool I am using)?

[image]

Comment: Was not able to reproduce, check your existing types